# Connection properties error when starting JBoss as a Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jboss, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to install the content management system Polopoly on my PC.  I get the following error when I run the mvn p:run command (this is intended to start up the Polopoly installation with an embedded database, jboss and web container):

```
Failed to execute goal com.polopoly.extensions-maven-plugin:10.6.1-fp1
1-c871a5b:run (default-cli) on project myproject: Could not deploy com.polopoly.
extensions-maven-plugin:import-scan: Could not scan content: Could not create
content importer: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to read
connection properties. Could not get connection properties from 'http://localho
st:8081/connection-properties/connection.properties', nor from backup 'C:\Users\
hollandv\AppData\Local\Temp\http___localhost_8081_connection-properties_connecti
on.properties'. ->
```

The detailed version of the error is as follows:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.polopoly.extensions-maven-plugin:10.6.1-fp1
1-c871a5b:run (default-cli) on project myproject: Could not deploy com.polopoly.
extensions-maven-plugin:import-scan: Could not scan content: Could not create
content importer: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to read
connection properties. Could not get connection properties from 'http://localho
st:8081/connection-properties/connection.properties', nor from backup 'C:\Users\
hollandv\AppData\Local\Temp\http___localhost_8081_connection-properties_connecti
on.properties'. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal c
om.polopoly.extensions-maven-plugin:10.6.1-fp11-c871a5b:run (default-cli) on p
roject myproject: Could not deploy com.polopoly.extensions-maven-plugin:import
-scan
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Could not deploy com.po
lopoly.extensions-maven-plugin:import-scan
at com.polopoly.maven.AbstractExecutePluginMojo.executePlugin(AbstractEx
ecutePluginMojo.java:85)
at com.polopoly.maven.PolopolyRunMojo.execute(PolopolyRunMojo.java:28)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Could not scan content
at com.polopoly.maven.ContentScanMojo.execute(ContentScanMojo.java:299)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:101)
at com.polopoly.maven.AbstractExecutePluginMojo.executePlugin(AbstractEx
ecutePluginMojo.java:83)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not create cont
ent importer: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to read con
nection properties.
at com.polopoly.maven.util.MavenPluginContentImporter.createImporter(Mav
enPluginContentImporter.java:60)
at com.polopoly.maven.util.MavenPluginContentImporter.<init>(MavenPlugin
ContentImporter.java:24)
at com.polopoly.maven.ContentScanMojo.createImporter(ContentScanMojo.jav
a:306)
at com.polopoly.maven.ContentScanMojo.execute(ContentScanMojo.java:192)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to read connec
tion properties.
at com.polopoly.plugin.ContentImporter.<init>(ContentImporter.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.polopoly.maven.util.MavenPluginContentImporter.createImporter(Mav
enPluginContentImporter.java:45)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not get connection properties from 'http:/
/localhost:8081/connection-properties/connection.properties', nor from backup 'C
:\Users\hollandv\AppData\Local\Temp\http__localhost_8081_connection-properties
connection.properties'.
at com.polopoly.application.BackedupConnectionProperties.retrieveAndStor
e(BackedupConnectionProperties.java:188)
at com.polopoly.application.BackedupConnectionProperties.retrieveAndBack
up(BackedupConnectionProperties.java:112)
at com.polopoly.application.BackedupConnectionProperties.retrieveAndBack
up(BackedupConnectionProperties.java:79)
at com.polopoly.application.ConnectionProperties.<init>(ConnectionProper
ties.java:219)
at com.polopoly.plugin.ContentImporter.<init>(ContentImporter.java:51)
... 32 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

I've verified that the Jetty Maven plugin has been configured with p.connectionPropertiesUrl ${polopoly.connection-properties} in the project's pom.xml file, however this has not resolved the issue.  Has anyone else had this problem and do you know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of maven you use? Try a maven version 3.0.x :) and it will work!

what are the maven commands you use?

try:

```
mvn clean install -Pall
mvn jboss:start
mvn jetty:run-all
```

best regards
Rene

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using version 3.0.5.  It turned out that part of the problem was that McAfee antivirus was using the same port that Polopoly was attempting to connect via.  Once I changed the Polopoly port, I was able to start it successfully.